# When should I use спрашивать and when просить?

Tags: глаголы

When to translate the word "ask" to Russian as:

1. **Спрашивать** (like in "asking a question")
2. **Просить** (like in "asking a favor")

How to differentiate these cases?

Comment: This site is about Russian, not about English.

Comment: You may have better luck in [english.SE]

Comment: I think Geo is asking (no pun intended) when to use спрашивать vs. просить. So the question is about Russian.

Comment: Dima, yes that's exactly what I meant, thanks!

Comment: So YellowSky and AleksG:  So you're implying that if this person goes to English Language & Usage and posts the question "When should I use cпрашивать and when просить?" he'll get an answer? How is this an English question? Honestly, sometimes the pettiness on this site is absolutely dizzying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спрашивать is to ask **about** something, or to inquire. Просить is to ask **for** something, or to ask somebody to do something, or to request.

But it gets worse, because it would be wrong to translate "to ask a question" as "спрашивать вопрос". The correct form is "задавать вопрос".

> I asked you a question. - Я **задал** тебе вопрос.
>
> I asked you about your work. - Я **спросил** тебя о твоей работе.

Comment: Another way to translate просить instead of "to ask" is "to request" and that is related to просьба = request.

Comment: Good point! Thank you. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Спрашивать` is to ask a question.
`Просить` is to ask anything else.

Examples:

- Спросил, который час.
- Попросил сказать, который час.
- Попросил воды.
- Спросил, где можно попить воды.

There is also a word `запрашивать` which is about information:

- `спросил информацию` - WRONG
- `попросил информацию` - WRONG
- `запросил информацию` - RIGHT

One can also use `запрашивать` instead of `просить` in bueracratic contexts:

- `Металлургический комбинат запросил пять тысяч тонн металлолома`.

To confise you even more,

- in Russian cant language (fenya) the word `спрашивать` has entirely different meaning.  Use the word `поинтересоваться` instead.
- in 19 century, the word `спросил` oftenly meant `попросил`, i. e.

  - `Он медлил — он спросил огня.` (А. С. Пушкин "Выстрел")